# css vmax doesnt work in Chrome 79 properly?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm trying to make square page for mobile gadgets. And something goes wrong.
Google Chrome 79.0.3945.88
Opera 65.0.3467.72
My screen resolution is 4K on Windows 10 x64
Here is video how it works wrong https://youtu.be/cxF9pWf7i5g

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background: black;
        }
        .div1 {
            height: 100vmax;
            width: 100vmax;
            background: red;
            padding: 1vmax;
            border: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .div2 {
             height: 98vmax;
             width: 98vmax;
             background: grey;
             border: 1vmax solid yellow;
         }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="div1">
        <div class="div2"> &nbsp; </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Cant post images. So URIs:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyRJV.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/33e53.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjjsW.png

Comment: Interesting. I don't see the same thing on Chrome 79 on Mac.